# Ionic Angular – just parts of the component are visible

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an ionic angular app which has the following structure:

[image]

I'm loading the front part via `loadChildren` and each tab as well. I have followed the tab angular example from ionic trough the CLI. From what I can see is that a not necessary `router-outlet` is created and the specific lazy loaded module doesn't have the correct height set.

<strike>Here is a part of my project: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/EvQtFhHv2v8oEMCksoKK?p=catalogue&utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=banner&utm_campaign=next</strike>

[image]
[image]

**UPDATE:**

Updated Plunker: https://next.plnkr.co/edit/VgyyF5a1SeXG4iuU

Comment: Could you share your source code and the margin paddin figures at the bottom of the panel of the style tabs when you press F12 in your browser, please?

Comment: Hey, @levolutionniste. I have updated the plunker (tell me whats missing, I can not share the hole project...). I haven't applied any styles to the tabs bar (so it must be the ionic default). I think it has something to do with the loaded module because before `app-explore` ionic loads modules with `ion-router-outlet` but at `<ion-router-outlet name="explore" class="hydrated">` it is loading a `ng-component` with a `router-outlet`...

Comment: I asked you to show the code of your html page and to inspect  this dev tool part in your browser http://prntscr.com/lucm62 so that we can have a relevant look on your code.

Comment: Ah sorry I missunderstood that. Here is the HTML: https://hastebin.com/awefusobir.xml.

Comment: The "Box-Modell" is telling margin and padding zero on this elements: ion-router-outlet, ng-component, router-outlet,app-explore .. which element do you want to see? I will make a screenshot of the "Layout"-Tab

Comment: General question, do I need to mention you or do you get a notification when I just reply as a comment? @levolutionniste

Comment: I have noticed that it is working when I add explore etc. as a component to front-routing. That would fix it temp. but I really would like to get the lazy load working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using the latest 4.x beta. Tabs has been changed in the latest release